# How to convert long to NSString in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I try to convert `long (value: 454555)` to `NSString`. But everytime I had tried it, I got garbage value like `@"-5026338884877204098"`.
How can I convert it same with 454555?

Comment: Hello welcome to stack overflow! Please post the code that you've tried, see: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize a NSString by

```
NSString *a =  @(454555).stringValue;
```

Here you can put all mathematical type value in the brackets,like

```
NSString *a =  @(0.1).stringValue;//a float value
NSString *a =  @(9223372036854775807).stringValue;//it's a longlong value
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
        long l = 454555;
        NSString * s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", l];
```

Note this is not locale aware ... but handy and sounds like the man you are looking for for your job. Here the %ld means a l=long d=decimal/int (ie long) value is next up in the parameters.

**EDIT**

If you like the `@`-way just execute the code below.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
        for ( long i = 0; i < 1000000; i ++ )
        {
            // Direct ...
            NSString * s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", i ];
        }
        NSLog(@"1");
        for ( long i = 0; i < 1000000; i ++ )
        {
            // Indirect via NSNumber ...
            NSString * s = @(i).stringValue;
        }
        NSLog(@"2");
    }

    return 0;
}
```